# Go cannot use name (type []string) as type string for ...string argument

Tags: go, slice, variadic-functions

i have this problem during compiling this code:

```
./greet.go:11:29: cannot use name (type []string) as type string in argument to CheckStringsAreUppercase
```

But i dont understand why. `name ...string` and `words ...string` have exactly same type. What's going on?

```
func Greet(name ...string) string {
        helloWord := "Hello"
    
        if CheckStringsAreUppercase(name) {
            return strings.ToUpper(helloWord)
        }
    
        return helloWord
    }
    
    func CheckStringsAreUppercase(words ...string) bool {
        for _, word := range words {
            if !CheckStringIsUppercase(word) {
                return true
            }
        }
    
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `...` notation (in a function signature) denotes a variadic parameter, which, inside that function scope is equivalent to a slice of that type, so `...string` is equivalent to `[]string`.

When you pass N parameters into a variadic function, all of them must be assignable to the type `T` of the vararg.

So by passing the parameter as `CheckStringsAreUppercase(name)` the type of `name` is effectively `[]string`, but `[]string` is *not assignable* to the type `string` of the variadic parameter `...string`, hence your compiler error.

The correct way to "explode" a slice into a variadic parameter is to use the three dots `...` after the variable name: `CheckStringsAreUppercase(name...)`

Answer (score 3):

Use this syntax:

```
        if CheckStringsAreUppercase(name...) {
            return strings.ToUpper(helloWord)
        }
```